# Create dependency property for WPF Window itself in its code behind xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, dependency-properties

I have a WPF window which I have changed its borders, title bar and buttons for a custom one. Separately in a ResourceDictionary I have defined the Style that I want to apply to my WPF window.
Then I bind that style to my WPF Window using below line of code:

```
Style="{DynamicResource CustomWindowStyle}"
```

Please see all my code posted in another thread that I created to ask for other things. Refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75340793/21095540) to see the code (I want to avoid repeating here again).

Now what I am trying to do is to create some custom properties (MyCustomProperty01, MyCustomProperty02) to that WPF Window, some like below:

**myDialogView.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="myApp.Views.myDialogView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:myApp.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:myApp.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}" 
        WindowStyle="None"

        MyCustomProperty01 = "true"
        MyCustomProperty02 = "true">
```

...and then in the code-behind of this WPF window (xaml.cs) I want to define those dependency properties MyCustomProperty01 and MyCustomProperty02, the ones you see above in the code snippet for the Window.

So I create those dependency properties in the code-behind as below.

**myDialogView.xaml.cs (code-behind):**

```
namespace myApp.Views
{
    public partial class myDialogView: Window
    {
        public myDialogView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty01Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustomProperty01",
                                        typeof(bool),
                                        typeof(myDialogView),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool MyCustomProperty01
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(MyCustomProperty01Property );
            set => SetValue(MyCustomProperty01Property , value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyCustomProperty02Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyCustomProperty02",
                                        typeof(bool),
                                        typeof(myDialogView),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool MyCustomProperty02
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(MyCustomProperty02Property );
            set => SetValue(MyCustomProperty02Property , value);
        }
    }
}
```

So when I start typing these dependency properties MyCustomProperty01 and MyCustomProperty01 for the window in the xaml view, intellisense looks like it is not recognizing those dependency properties. So what am I doing wrong? Could some tell me how I can achieve this with some code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to registerattached for this to work.

I'm not 100% sure why, I just know it won't work with the usual dependency property.

I think it's because it's in a window tag and it's "really" a myDialogView causes the issue.

Here's an example attached property I have:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TakeMapPictureProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "TakeMapPicture",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(MainWindow),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false
          , new PropertyChangedCallback(TakeMapPictureChanged)
        ));

    private static async void TakeMapPictureChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public static void SetTakeMapPicture(UIElement element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(TakeMapPictureProperty, value);
    }
    public static bool GetTakeMapPicture(UIElement element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(TakeMapPictureProperty);
    }
```

And in the window tag

```
    local:MainWindow.TakeMapPicture="{Binding CaptureMap}"
```

Where you might want to use the one dependency property in several user controls or windows, you can define the attached properties in a separate class.  There are a couple of ways to do this but the one I prefer looks like:

```
public class MainWin : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MapFileProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "MapFile",
         typeof(string),
         typeof(MainWin),
         new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty
             , new PropertyChangedCallback(MapFileChanged)
        ));
```

And that is used inside a window tag:

```
    local:MainWin.MapFile="{Binding Path=MapFile}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the property on the wrong element (locally/attribute syntax):

```xml
<Window ... MyCustomProperty01="True" />
```

Of course, `Window` does not have a `MyCustomProperty01` property.
But `myDialogView` has this property.

To set this property, either use a `Style`:

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="myDialogView">
      <Setter Property="MyCustomProperty01" Value="True" />
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

Or set it locally on the proper `myDialogView` element. But you would have to create a derived type (e.g., `myExtendedDialogView`), so that you can define `myDialogView` (the base type) as the root element.
Note how the root element is always the base type of the actual extending type: for example `<Window />` of `MainWindow` or `<UserControl />` of `MyUserControl` or `<Page />` of `MyPage` or `<Application />` of `App`.
Specify the `partial class` (the derived type that provides the code-behind file) using the `x:Class` directive on the root element:

```
<myDialogView x:Class="myExtendedDialogView"
              MyCustomProperty01="True">
</myDialogView >
```

```cs
// Define the extended class as partial (with code-behind)
// and the base class that contains the custom properties as a simple class (no code-behind)
partial class myExtendedDialogView : myDialogView
{
  public myExtendedDialogView() => InitializeComponent();
}
```

```cs
// Base class used as XAML root element.
// This type has no code-behind file (not partial)
class myDialogView : Window
{
  // Dependency properties
}
```

Comment: I am trying the same thing, as Kiraski. Your solution works for me but I am facing an issue with dependency properties... Can you please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75802650/issue-with-wpf-dependency-properties-on-visual-studio-properties-window ?